# Two identical CSS stylesheets loading differently

Tags: css, amazon-s3

The following two files contain identical content, as confirmed by a diff checker.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.craft.do/_next/static/css/53915118cb795b35.css" data-n-g=""/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opine-development.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/zxxtq6iozbczyy8zqxtlozjxhvpe?response-content-disposition=inline&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIATEKXMHF3YUQ3TDWF%2F20230216%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230216T231116Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=f5ab9461e698f7026f0a5d6476709f714fa32e12cdf16a480808aec2abb368f8" data-n-g=""/>
```

Both open correctly to identical content when in the browser.

However, only the first one is read and processed correctly by an HTML page that the content is on. Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: Are you certain there are no errors when you check in your browsers inspect devtools facility? I’m seeing request expired, but I don’t know enough about aws.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Good to know rob!